# error while running Logstash.conf file

Tags: linux, unix, elasticsearch, logstash

In my unix system, I have installed Elasticsearch and Logstash but when I am trying to run logstash.conf file by the command (logstash agent -f ../first-pipeline.conf) I am getting the following error :

```
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2

NotImplementedError: stat.st_dev unsupported or native support failed to load dev_major at 
org/jruby/RubyFileStat.java:205

nix_inode at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:28

inode at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:32

inode at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:106

watch at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:96

_discover_file at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:313
each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
each at org/jruby/RubyEnumerator.java:274

_discover_file at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:304

watch at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:95

call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281

synchronized at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:357

synchronize at org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149

synchronized at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:357

watch at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:92

tail at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.8.1/lib/filewatch/tail_base.rb:73

tail at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/forwardable.rb:201

begin_tailing at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-file-2.2.5/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:288

each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
begin_tailing at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-file-2.2.5/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:288

run at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-file-2.2.5/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:292

inputworker at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342

start_input at /home/tomcat/ELK/logstash-2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:336
```

Comment: Which JVM do you have? Can you run `java -version` and tell us what the output is?

Comment: java version - 1.8 ,
64 bit server

Comment: Which implementation? OpenJDK or Oracle?

Comment: It seems to be similar to this: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3033

Comment: Ya I have read that and this issue is further addressed in : https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3127
in that he is trying to make a hard link of file libcrypt.so.1 to libcrypt.so. But this file is already present in my machine at address : usr/lib/libcrypt.so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did symlink and everything is ok now.

ln -s /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e /usr/lib64/crypt

Referring to https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3127

Comment: for me, its working on one machine with all same environment and without this symlink but failing in another environment.

Answer (score 1):

if use the alpine docker images, fix this:

```
ln -s /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/crypt
```